# Error building URDF behaviors when combining Image Target and Ground Plane Stage in the same scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am trying to build an application that could place the URDF digital double of a robotic arm in the exact position of the one in the real environment. In the testing stage, I am using image target to locate the digital double (model target of the base link of the robotic arm would be used after), and ground plane stage to check the setup and for other objects in the scene. When I scanned the image target, the digital double appeared for a blink and collapsed with only the base link remained due to the immovable property, then an incredibly large model of the robot (at least 10x bigger) appeared in the scene. The remained base link could receive commands from the UI while the URDF package failed to respond. I have no idea what happened, and would like to know if anybody has similar experience when applying different types of targets in the same scene.

I have no idea what happened as I am pretty new to this setup, and would like to know if anybody has similar experience when applying different types of targets in the same scene.